# Mutiple overlapping OR statements in R

Tags: r, function, data-cleaning

So I have some data that looks like this:

```
+-----------+------------+---------------+
| Land Type | Owner Type | Operator Type |
+-----------+------------+---------------+
| F         | P          | F             |
| F         | F          | F             |
| F         | P          | O             |
| T         | F          | P             |
+-----------+------------+---------------+
```

I would like to add a column labeled "allType" that takes an OR statement for each column, and adds a field. So if the row has all F's, then the corresponding allType should just be F. But if the row has a mix of F, P, T, or O, then the allType should reflect that.

```
+----------+-----------+--------------+--------------------------+
| landType | ownerType | operatorType |         allType          |
+----------+-----------+--------------+--------------------------+
| F        | P         | F            | Federal, Pprivate        |
| F        | F         | F            | Federal                  |
| F        | P         | O            | Federal, Private, Other  |
| T        | F         | P            | Tribal, Federal, Private |
+----------+-----------+--------------+--------------------------+
```

I currently ran an OR statement that looks like this, but they do not stack with commas the way I would like. And it doesnt allow for the double counting that I need.

```
# display private facility tag
data$allType[data$landType == 'P' | data$ownerType == 'P' | adata$operatorType == 'P'] ='Private'

# display Federal facility tag
data$allType[data$landType == 'F' | data$ownerType == 'F' | adata$operatorType == 'F'] ='Federal'

# display Federal facility tag
data$allType[data$landType == 'T' | data$ownerType == 'T' | adata$operatorType == 'T'] ='Tribal'

# display Federal facility tag
data$allType[data$landType == 'O' | data$ownerType == 'O' | adata$operatorType == 'O'] ='Other'
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to create a named vector to match the values in each of the columns and `unite` the columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate_all(~ setNames(c('Federal', "Private", "Other", "Tribal"), 
             c("F", "P", "O", "T"))[.]) %>% 
   unite(alllType, everything(), sep=", ") %>%
   bind_cols(df1, .)
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#  `Land Type` `Owner Type` `Operator Type` alllType                 
#* <chr>       <chr>        <chr>           <chr>                    
#1 F           P            F               Federal, Private, Federal
#2 F           F            F               Federal, Federal, Federal
#3 F           P            O               Federal, Private, Other  
#4 T           F            P               Tribal, Federal, Private
```

---

If we don't want the duplicate entries,

```
library(purrr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate_all(~ setNames(c('Federal', "Private", "Other", "Tribal"), 
          c("F", "P", "O", "T"))[.]) %>%
  transmute(allType =  pmap_chr(., ~ toString(unique(c(...))))) %>% 
  bind_cols(df1, .)
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#  `Land Type` `Owner Type` `Operator Type` allType                 
#* <chr>       <chr>        <chr>           <chr>                   
#1 F           P            F               Federal, Private        
#2 F           F            F               Federal                 
#3 F           P            O               Federal, Private, Other 
#4 T           F            P               Tribal, Federal, Private
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(`Land Type` = c("F", "F", "F", "T"), `Owner Type` = c("P", 
"F", "P", "F"), `Operator Type` = c("F", "F", "O", "P")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

akrun is, as always correct & fast, but in the meantime a base R solution, using named vectors:

```
df <- data.frame( "ownerType" = c("t","p", "f"),
                  "landType" = c("t","o","t"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df

vector <- c("Tribal", "Federal", "Private", "Other")
names(vector) <- c("t","p",'f', "o")

df$allType <- apply(df, 1, function(x) paste( vector[x], collapse = ", "))
df
```